# Holiday Approval /tracking

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, moss

Has anyone implemented a holiday workflow approval / tracking list in MOSS Sharepoint 2007?

Can anyone suggests other solutions? The solution below works fine ***but I am specifically looking for a way to lookup manager of the user who created the holiday request list item in the workflow.***

I have followed this link http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Kevin/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=39
which shows you how to create a custom workflow approval. Below are the steps outlined by the link.

1. User add new holiday item to list
2. Workflow kicks off
3. Wf has the manager hardcoded (**need a way to look this up, maybe from AD??**) and creates a Task for them to review the request.  If desired, this can include an email notification of the task
4. Manager reviews, adds comments and approves/denies request
5. User is notified of completed request

Many Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: i used http://edinkapic.blogspot.com/2008/05/user-profile-sharepoint-designer.html to get the users manager, it works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

We have used a custom developed InfoPath form and a simple Approval workflow to tackle this task.

Comment: Thanks any pointers to tutorials you used would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Sure, the easy part was making the basic form (Date of Vacation, Type of leave, etc)
The next part was inputting the username automatically.  We made a Web Service (google for 'getting a username via web service') to query the current user information, and automatically filled that into the default value of a text box.
Next, we created another web service to look up a manager.  The user would enter a manager's email, username, or lastname and the infopath form would query the web service to find it, and fill in the text box, also getting the email.  when submitted, the manager receive an email

Comment: Hi Kolten, thanks for the information. Do you know of a way to query the manager directly from a workflow? I have tried using SPDActivities LookupUserInfo though this doesn't query the userprofile. Or if you could post a walkthrough of your solution as I am new to infopath and webservices...and am short of time to research it... Many Thanks in advance.. Naveen